# DateTime object How to change the year to be the current year

Tags: php

I have a list of birthdates and I want to figure out what day of the week each birthday will be for this year.

Is there an easy way to modify the DateTime object to change the year to be the current year? That way I can use that to get the day of the week etc.

Say this is my date of birth object:

```
$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1986-07-26');
```

How do I modify that to be the current year or create a new object from it with the same date in the current year?

Once I have done that, I then just do something like:

```
$test = $dob->format('l');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `modify()` to increment/decrement to current year or use `setDate()` like this:

```php
$dob->setDate((int) date("Y"), (int)$dob->format('m'), (int)$dob->format('d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the date directly.

```php
$today = new DateTime();
$dob->setDate($today->format('Y'), $dob->format('m'), $dob->format('d'));

echo $dob->format('Y-m-d'); // 2019-07-26
```